# How to generate random matrix of arbitrary rank in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Is there any way in Julia to generate a random matrix that has some arbitrary/specified rank? For example, is there any function that would allow generating a random 3x3 matrix of rank 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a little on what you mean by "random matrix" (i.e. what distribution?), but `rand(3,2)*rand(2,3)` will produce a random matrix 3x3 matrix of rank 2 with some distribution.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to generate r random vectors (probability 1 of being independent) and fill the rest of the matrix with random (or predefined) linear combinations of the latter.

A minimalist solution is to just replicate some of the initial vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Generate a random matrix of the desired format, compute its SVD, set the lower singular values to zero according to the rank, reconstruct the rank-reduced matrix.

This should give a different kind of "random", at higher cost, than the one resulting from the multiplication of random matrices.